# Solus traffic flow

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect, solus

We install Solus in our host machines and run several containers. I've noted that after installation, solus modify iptables adding to Forward chain Solus_in and Solus_out. In those chains he is adding ip on our vps in this way

```
Chain SOLUSVM_TRAFFIC_IN 
 all  --  0.0.0.0/0            x.x.x.x (IP added to container)
 all  --  0.0.0.0/0            x.x.x.x (IP added to container)
```

I try to add my own rule in this chain but Solus override them after, so I add them in site our containers and everything is working properly. And know is my question, what if I want to specify rule to all containers, how to do this?

I tried to change INPUT chain in host server but traffic is passing some how still to Solus. I tried also change Forward chain and specify rule for forward to Solus for example

```
Chain FORWARD
 SOLUSVM_TRAFFIC_IN  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
 SOLUSVM_TRAFFIC_OUT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22
 DROP  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

And here is /etc/networks

```
default 0.0.0.0
loopback 127.0.0.0
link-local x.x.0.0
```

But it close traffic by container be ssh. So how this is working?

1. How traffic is passing eth0 even when there is a rule to block some
   ports.
2. Why I cannot my modiffication in FORWARD chain for Solus are
       not working?
3. How Solus is overwriting the SOLUSVM_TRAFFIC_IN chain?
4. And how to secure this Solus?

Thanks for all help, to understand this strange behavior